# Overhaul tags for Apple apps across OS X, iOS, watchOS, and tvOS

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently tags for Apple Apps are all over the place.

At first I thought it would be a good idea to have separate tags for each app on each platform like having [mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail.app) for OS X and [mobile-mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-mail) for iOS but that quickly gets out of hand with all the new platforms (tv and watch) and there isn't a simple naming convention to follow (why a prefix for one platform and a suffix for the other). Apple used to refer to Mail on iOS as Mobile Mail but now they do not. I think internally it is still MobileMail and NanoMail for the watch but most people wouldn't recognize them as such.

Thus I propose that we move tags for Apple apps that have the same name across platforms to use the `.app` suffix such as [mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail.app) and drop or make the `mobile` prefix a synonym. Then the user would just combine the app tag with the relevant platform to indicate which one they are interested in. Also we would still keep general nouns such as [maps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) and [photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) separate from their `.app` tags. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

.app only makes sense for OS X applications as this is the only one that shows .app. OS X users will unserstand .app but I think there will be new IOS users who will not understand .app as an extension (and the default for OS X is show no extension) so I think .app is only for experienced people. This is especially as auto complete will show the name without the .app and users will choose that.

I agree the mobile prefix makes no sense,

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, this should happen, since people would be able to search with `[mail] [ios]` or similar.** The search term would mean that all posts found would have both tags.

You can even test it out using [this search query](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imac+memory) for [imac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imac) and [memory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory)-tagged posts.